# Directional derivatives of two variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We investigate a function, $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ given by,

$$ f(x,y) = x^3y+ xy^3 −2 x^3 −6 xy^2 −x^2 +10 xy−y^2 −4 x+4 y−2 $$

a) Determine the directional of $f$ at (0, 1) in the direction towards the origin. Determine all directions in which the directional of $f$ at (0, 1) takes the value of 1.

b) Consider the circle, $C=[(x,y)|x^2+(y−2)^2 =2]$. Imagine a point that moves around $C$ counterclockwise. Determine for each position of the point of the directional of $f$ at the point in the point's movement. Explain that $C$ is part of the 0-level curve of $f$.

c) Determine all stationary points of $f$. Consider the points

$ P = (-1, 1),Q = (0, 0), R = (1, 0)$ and $S = (0, 2).$

d) Show that the restriction of $f$ to any straight line through $S$ has real local maximum is in $S$. Can we on this basis determine that $f$ has real local maximum in $S$? Having $f$ actual local maximum in $S$?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is a polynomial and thus differentiable everywhere, so directional derivatives are rather easy:

$$\nabla f(x,y)=\left(3x^2y+y^3-6x^2-6y^2-2x+10y-4,\,x^3+3xy^2-12xy+10x-2y+4\right)$$

So the directional derivative of $\;f\;$ at some point $\;(x_0,y_0)\;$ in the direction $\;\vec u\;$ is just

$$\nabla f(x_0,y_0)\cdot\frac{\vec u}{||\vec u||}$$

Observe that the direction fropm $\;(1,0)\;$ towards the origin is $\;(0,0)-(0,1)=(0,-1)\;$ , and this is already a unitary vector, so

$$\nabla f(0,1)\cdot (0,-1)=(1,2)\cdot(0,-1)=-2$$

For the second problem, you have to find all direction vectors $\;(u_1,u_2)\;$ such that

$$1=\nabla f(0,1)\cdot(u_1,u_2)=(1,2)\cdot(u_1,u_2)=u_1+2u_2$$